# Unresolved class 'HeadlineFragment' in the fragment tag

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

it gives the error " Unresolved class 'HeadlineFragment' " in the line :
android:name="HeadlineFragment"

```
  <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/headline_fragment"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:name=".HeadlineFragment"
        >

    </fragment>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide full link to your `Fragment`

Example

```
<fragment
        ...
        android:name="com.your.packagename.HeadlineFragment"
        >
```